# Resolving only some files in a git merge conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

What if there's a merge conflict with two files.
Only person A is familiar with file A
and only person B is familiar with file B

I'm new to git.
So would it be possible for person A to resolve the conflicts in file A
and then hand it over to person B to handle conflicts with file B?

Or does the unsolved conflict make it impossible to do git push?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is not possible to hand over a conflict to another person. And in order to push you've to solve the conflicts first.

However if Person A doesn't know anything about file A, Person A shouldn't edit file A which then wouldn't cause a merge conflict?

Answer (score 1):

As [Kevin answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575687/1256452), you cannot hand the partially-resolved merge conflict to someone else other than by sharing a working tree.  You can only push *commits* (not files), and commits are by definition resolved.

What you can do—this requires a lot of manual cooperation and hand work—is resolve your conflicts "correctly", resolve the remaining conflicts "incorrectly" but *mark them as such*, add and commit the result, and deliver the resulting commit to the next person.  That person can *start their own merge*, take *your* (presumably marked in some manner) *correct* resolutions (from your separate commit, presumably on a separate branch) and put them in their partial merge, and work on the remaining conflicts.  They can repeat this process as needed.

Git needs a mechanism by which this can be automated, but does not have one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really very hard to do, you just have to know who's responsible for resolving which conflicts.

Say you've got `master` and `fixups` branches, and a merge produces conflicts in `fileA` and `fileB` that you don't want to resolve, so you get Alice and Bob to do partial merges, Alice fixing the `fileA` and Bob fixing the `fileB` conflicts, with fake resolutions for the files you don't need from them. They push their results back to you as `partial-merge-from-Alice` and `partial-merge-from-Bob`

Now you do the merge, it produces those conflicts, and you say `git checkout partial-merge-from-Alice filea` and `git checkout partial-merge-from-Bob fileB`.

You're done. Commit the result and everybody goes home.

If it's more complicated, add `--patch` to your checkouts from the partial merges, and pick and choose which resolutions you want.